# Проблема при импорте-экспорте данных из одной базы в другую через текстовый файл. MSSQL 2012

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

Добрый день.
Пытаюсь перенести кусок таблицы с боевого сервера на тестовый с помощью импорта-экспорта mssql managment studio. Импортирую данные на боевой базе в текстовый файл. Там есть одно поле типа int nullable.

Экспортирую эти данные из файла на тестовой базе и это интовое поле импортироваться не хочет,какой тип ему не указывай. Ошибки на этапе Executing. В файле значения этого поля примерно от 0 до 400, в базе от -30 до 4000 примерно.

Когда указываю тип при конверсии двухбайтовый или больше интеджер получаю это:

```
Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "ItemOrder" returned status value 2 and status text "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".
```

Когда указываю тип string, получаю это:
`Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "Description" returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.".` 
Указывать Ignore on Truncate пробовал что global что для конкретного поля.

Погуглив встречал советы поиграться с типами (не помогает) и импортировать через аксесс, что невозможно так как его нигде не стоит.

У кого-нибудь есть советы по разрешению этой проблемы?

Comment: попробуйте bulk insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам нужно сделать, а не разобраться с проблемой, то я бы поступил так:

1. Генерация скрипта создания таблицы с данными.
2. Выполнение этого скрипта на тестовом сервере.
3. Удаление "лишних" строк.

Comment: Да, спасибо, в результате и разобрался написав скрипт генератор. Просто не ожидал на ровном месте со стандартной утилитой получить такие проблемы...

Comment: > написав скрипт генератор. 

Ну, скрипт писать было не обязательно. Создание скрипта - штатное средство в MS.